# Binomial summation with alternating terms?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

How do I solve problems of type :$$\sum_{k=1}^{(n+1)/2}\binom n{2k-1}x^k\text{ or }\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom n{2k}x^k$$

I tried transferring the binomial to $n-1$ but the repeating $x^k$ makes it weird.

Edit: I started with $$(1+x)^n+(1-x)^n$$ with $x=\sqrt5$

Comment: @robjohn but the power of x will be changed then no?

Comment: I don't see the question, now. Your edit says you started with what seemed to be almost the answer.

Comment: the power of $x$ will be $2k$ in what you started with, so you will need to use $\sqrt{x}$ in the final form.

Comment: I cant really expand $(1+\sqrt5)^{16}+(1-\sqrt5)^{16}$ directly, can I?

Comment: why not? the odd powers of $\sqrt5$ will cancel and you'll be left with twice the even powers of $\sqrt5$, which are integer powers of $5$.

Comment: That will end up being $$2\sum_{k=0}^8\binom{16}{2k}5^k$$

Comment: By that logic, I can also expand the q i posted and get result faster. By that logic you can also calculate $1+x+x^2+\dots x^n$ by hand but ofcorse the formula's way shorter

Comment: @robjohn The question is is there a closed form or need to do it manually?

Comment: You've given the closed form: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2k}x^k=\frac12\left(\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^n+\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)^n\right)$$

Comment: You can work the same way with the odd part: $$\sum_{k=1}^{(n+1)/2}\binom{n}{2k-1}x^k=\frac{\sqrt{x}}2\left(\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^n-\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)^n\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Okay, now that you've added some context, I think I can answer this question. The Binomial Theorem says
$$
\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{k/2}\tag1
$$
and
$$
\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^kx^{k/2}\tag2
$$
Adding $(2)$ to $(1)$ and dividing by $2$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12\left(\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^n+\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)^n\right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\overbrace{\frac{1+(-1)^k}2}^{\text{$1$ when $k$ is even}}x^{k/2}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2k}x^k\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$ and dividing by $2$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12\left(\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^n-\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)^n\right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\overbrace{\frac{1-(-1)^k}2}^{\text{$1$ when $k$ is odd}}x^{k/2}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{(n+1)/2}\binom{n}{2k-1}x^{k-\frac12}\tag4
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Consider $$(1+x)^n+(1-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(1+(-1)^k)x^k$$
and
$$
(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(1-(-1)^k)x^k
$$
What can you say about $1+(-1)^k$ and $1-(-1)^k$ when $k$ is even or odd?

Comment: I should've clarified. I started from here and wanted exact value of the term

Comment: @AFalseName: please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the binomial theorem twice,
$$
(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{\binom{n}{k}x^k}\\
(1-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^k}
$$
If $E$ is the sum of the even terms, and $O$ the sum of the odd terms, we have
$$
(1+x)^n=E+O\\
(1-x)^n=E-O
$$

Comment: My bad but that's where i started with $x=\sqrt5$

Comment: So $E=((1+\sqrt 5)^n+(1-\sqrt 5)^n)/2$ etc.  What's the problem?